# gsub (r) not replacing pattern"S+U "

Tags: r, string, gsub

I am trying to correct a vector of strings with a for loop, this particular one is no working

```
gsub("S+U ", "t",  "S+U S+U lag")
```

I also tried with grepl and it detects S+, +U, but with S+U does not work. Does someone know why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You should escape `+` by `\\+`

```
> gsub("S\\+U ", "t", "S+U S+U lag")
[1] "ttlag"
```

or you can enable `fixed = TRUE`

```
> gsub("S+U ", "t", "S+U S+U lag", fixed = TRUE)
[1] "ttlag"
```

Comment: This answer provides both an explanation (as requested by OP) and two solutions.

Comment: @Limey akrun gives a detailed explanation, not me.

Comment: he’s edited his answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `fixed` as TRUE as `+` is a metacharacter for one or more.  So, in the regex mode, it will search for one or more 'S' followed by an U.  Either use `fixed = TRUE` or escape (`\\+`) to evaluate literally

```
gsub("S+U ", "t",  "S+U S+U lag", fixed = TRUE)
```